# Why am I able to allocate more memory to an array than my computer actually has

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am able to successfully run the code:

```
char* p = new char[34493878088];
cout << "Success at " << 34493878088 << " bytes" << endl;
delete[] p;
```

which as I understand allocates a 34 gigabyte char array.  However, my computer only has 16 gigabytes of ram and my pagefile is only 3 gigabytes so how is this possible?

Comment: Are you using Linux? That's called [over committing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment). [what is the purpose of memory overcommitment on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441364/44425)

Comment: Computers now use "virtual memory managers" along with address randomization. Virtual memory is what you ask to reserve and the pages are not actually mapped to physical RAM by the system until you write something to them. Each OS has it's own memory manager, but that is it in a nutshell. If you loop and attempt to write a character to each byte and do something with the bytes that has side effects, like a comparison, etc... (so your compiler just can't optimize the use of the array away) you will run out of memory.

Comment: @RetiredNinja new does not return NULL on failure, it throws a std::bad_alloc exception.

Comment: [Will Microsoft Windows 10 overcommit memory?](https://superuser.com/q/1194263/241386)

Comment: Please guys don't answer in comments ! Even a small answer is still an answer ;)

Comment: @Fareanor: Only a hint to a other web resource is not an answer in the standards of SO. So it is quite fine to help with comments if the author has no time to give more background info to the posted resource.

Comment: @Klaus Indeed but I was not talking for the single-link comment

Answer (score 1):

The reserved address space ("virtual memory") is not mapped immediately into the physical memory. This is delayed till the memory is accessed.

When you first time access the memory location, a page fault interrupt initially happens, and only then the kernel configures the memory controller (that is a piece of hardware, part of CPU) to place a page of physical memory for your program at that address location. The program is then resumed from where it was interrupted and does not see these things happening.

A region in address space that is formally reserved but never accessed does not use the actual physical memory and can be larger than the amount of the physical memory available.